# get Sqlite Id with onListItemClick

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey i have a database and i would like to toast the an information which corresponds to the clicked item of the list who is also in the database  :

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT mac FROM test4 where _id=", null);
    while(c2.moveToNext()) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I know how to get the postion but i want to display the information which are also in my database :

```
db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("testDB4", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test4(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,mac VARCHAR,mdp VARCHAR,obj VARCHAR);");
```

for example display mac which is in the same line of the id clicked in my database

Comment: look at the `onListItemClick` method definition. Now look at the last parameter `long id`. That's your db id.

Comment: @njzk2 Sort of. That's the ID from the adapter's `getItemId()` method. If he's using the standard `CursorAdapter` or a subclass thereof, then it will be the value of the _id column in that row.

Comment: @Karakuri: that is to be assumed, yes. If the OP has an adapter implementation that returns an id that is not the id they want, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: You can tag the view in your listview with the id. Then retrieve it in the onListItemClick and use it to query the database. You will have to set the tag in your listviewadapter.